# Отрисовка таблицы в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Есть PHP цикл, который рисует таблицу

```
<table border="1">
<?php
$i = 1;
$k = 1;
while ($i <= $v_value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $t = 1;
    while ($t <= $g_value) {
        echo "<td align='center' id=".$k." ondblclick='postCell()' onclick='selectCell(".$k.")'></td>";
        $t++;
        $k++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Для каждой ячейки задаётся уникальный ID по порядку. Можно кликнуть на любую ячейку, и выполняется JS скрипт

Хочу сделать игру на подобии пиксельной змейки (По порядку закрашиваются нужные ячейки нужным цветом). Подскажите, как можно это таблицу отрисовать в canvas?

Я нашёл код шахматной доски

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("chessboard");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Размеры холста
    canvas.width  = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    // Внешняя рамка для доски
    context.strokeRect(15, 15, 266, 266);
    // Внутренняя рамка для доски
    context.strokeRect(18, 18, 260, 260);
    // Закрашиваем внутреннюю область черным цветом
    context.fillRect(20, 20, 256, 256);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
        context.clearRect(20 + i * 32, 20 + j * 32, 32, 32);
        context.clearRect(20 + (i + 1) * 32, 20 + (j + 1) * 32, 32, 32);
      }
</script>
```

Но не получилось там отрисовать таблицу

Comment: не очень понятно какой должен быть результат

Comment: https://sun9-72.userapi.com/c855220/v855220089/14b417/P2wGgA2K5qs.jpg
Создаётся вот такая пиксельная доска. С помощью JS каждую ячейку можно закрасить каким то цветом

Comment: Что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Отрисовать таблицу так, что бы каждая клетка была кликабельна. Тоесть, если кликнуть на какую то клетку, она закрасилась выбранным цветом. С backend проблемы нет, именно фронт не получается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное можно сделать как-то так:

```js
let imgData, size = 25, 
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    save = () => imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
    restore = () => context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0),
    snap = n => Math.floor((+n)/size),
    data = Array(snap(canvas.width)*snap(canvas.height)).fill(0),
    xy = e => [snap(e.layerX) * size,snap(e.layerY) * size];

save();

canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  restore();
  let i = snap(e.layerY)*snap(canvas.width) + snap(e.layerX);
  rect(e, data[i] ? 'white' : `hsl(${Math.random()*360},77%,77%)`);
  data[i] = data[i] ? 0 : 1;
  save()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  restore();
  rect(e, '#0002')
})

function rect(e, color) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(...xy(e), size, size);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #0004;
  margin:-6px;
}

.as-console-wrapper{
  height:44px
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=625 height=150></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что мне нужно)

Comment: А как можно закрасить квадрат через консольку, а не по нажатию на ячейку?

Comment: @Тимур я не особо понял что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Ну, допустим, я написал в консоль paint(392, 'green');
И ячейка номер 392 закрасилась в зелёный цвет

Comment: @Тимур да сколько угодно, только не в сниппете на so, тут все огорожено..